# Use of undefined root path

Tags: php

I'm following a tutorial there I get an undefined constant ROOT_PATH. I have a register page that includes a file called path.php that contains the constant ROOT_PATH, below that I have another include that links a file called users like this.

```
<?php



include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/database/db.php");
include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/helpers/validateUser.php");

$errors = array();
$username = '';
$email = '';
$password = '';
$passwordConf = '';


if(isset($_POST['register-btn'])){
    $errors = validateUser($_POST);
  

    if(count($errors) ===0){
        

        unset($_POST['register-btn'], $_POST['passwordConf']);
        $_POST['admin'] = 0;
    
        $_POST['password'] = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    
        $user_id = create('users', $_POST);
        $user = selectOne('users', ['id' => $user_id]);
    
        

        $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $user['admin'];
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'you are now logged in';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';

        if($_SESSION['admin']){
            header('location: ' . BASE_URL . '/admin/dashboard.php');

        } else {
            header('location: ' . BASE_URL . '/index.php');
        }

        header('location: ' . BASE_URL . '/index.php');
        exit();

    } else{
        $username = $_POST ['username'];
        $email = $_POST ['email'];
        $password = $_POST ['password'];
        $passwordConf = $_POST ['password'];
    }

if(isset($_POST['login-btn'])){
    $errors = validateLogin($_POST);

    if(count($errors) === 0){
        $user = selectOne('users', ['username' => $_POST['username']]);

        if ($user && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])){

            $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
            $_SESSION['admin'] = $user['admin'];
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'you are now logged in';
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    
            if($_SESSION['admin']){
                header('location: ' . BASE_URL . '/admin/dashboard.php');
    
            } else {
                header('location: ' . BASE_URL . '/index.php');
            }
    
            header('location: ' . BASE_URL . '/index.php');
        }
            exit();
        } else{
            array_push($errors, 'wrong credentials');
        }
     }
   }
```

now according to him I do not need to link path.php in users because on the register page there I linked path.php goes to the users.php but I still get this message:
Warning: Use of undefined constant ROOT_PATH - assumed 'ROOT_PATH' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpblogtut\app\controlers\users.php on line 5

this is register.php :

```
   <?php include("path.php"); ?>
<?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/controlers/users.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- header -->
  <?php include(ROOT_PATH . '/app/includes/header.php');?>
  <!-- // header -->
  <div class="auth-content">
    <form action="register.php" method="post">
      <h3 class="form-title">Register</h3>
    <?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/helpers/formErrors.php");?>
      
      <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" class="text-input">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" class="text-input">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" class="text-input">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="passwordConf" value="<?php echo $passwordConf; ?>" class="text-input">
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" name="register-btn" class="btn">Register</button>
      </div>
      <p class="auth-nav">Or <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL . '/login.php' ?> ">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is path.php :

```
<?php
    define('ROOT_PATH',realpath(dirname('_FILE_'))); 
    define("BASE_URL", 'http://localhost/phpblogtut');
```

Comment: What's the flow here? Is `users.php` always included like it is in the first snippet, or are you calling the file some other way as well (which the error message suggests)? We need to see more context, like where the request comes in, which path it takes through your application to reach `users.php`.

Comment: You're also defining the path wrong. It should either be: `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))` (no quotes and double underscores) or the cleaner version: `realpath(__DIR__)`.

Comment: I would rather set all constants the application needs as soon as possible, like in a bootstrap-file that always gets called in the beginning of every request (like if you're using the front controller pattern, I would put it in the index-file that always gets called.)

Comment: I updated so you can see all the code

Comment: debugging: `var_dump(defined('ROOT_PATH'), __FILE__.__LINE__);` Add this after the 'define' in the register file and before the use of the constant in the user file. It will show you what is happening.

Comment: Tbh, I would rather recommend that you look into the MVC-pattern (with a front controller and a router that handle the requests). That will pass all requests to index.php where you can set up everything you need in the app (like any constants.)

Comment: I will look into it. The odd thing is in the tutorial comments there are no one with similiar issues, so i'm at loss what it can be.   The debugging thing I don't understand, there is no define in the register file

Comment: Sorry,  wrong file... whatever file you define 'PATH_ROOT' in  `path.php`? It is so you can see what order the files are run  in and check that the constant is defined when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing to include path.php in users.php

your users.php file should be

```
<?php include_once("path.php"); ?> // **include path.php in users.php**
<?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/database/db.php");
    include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/helpers/validateUser.php"); ?>
```

and the register.php file should be

```
<?php include_once("path.php"); ?> // remove this line if this files includes users.php
    <?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/controlers/users.php"); ?>
```

Comment: If they remove `path.php` from the register.php, it won't have `ROOT_PATH` it needs in the line below and they would get the same error but in another file.

Comment: actually my mean is if the users.php file already included in register.php then they can ignore to include path.php in that.

Comment: Since register.php is including users.php using the constant ROOT_PATH, then register.php _needs_ to include path.php _before_ it includes users.php, or the constant won't be defined yet. You can't use a constant to load the file that defines that constant.

Comment: According to the guy i'm following. I don't need to and he isn't doing it either. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8D7cz7dQFI4&list=PL3pyLl-dgiqD0eKYJ-XSxrHaRh-zsA2tP&index=11  07:25

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a constant, you have to include the file containing the constant, if it was not declared in the same PHP file.
So, you need to include `path.php`.

```
<?php 
    include('path.php');
    include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/database/db.php");
    include(ROOT_PATH . "/app/helpers/validateUser.php");
```

Could you link the tutorial?

Comment: 'define' creates the name in global namespace. They are available everywhere after they are defined. There are a couple of useful functions: 'defined' and 'get_defined_constants' .

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8D7cz7dQFI4&list=PL3pyLl-dgiqD0eKYJ-XSxrHaRh-zsA2tP&index=11 07:25

Comment: @RyanVincent If the webserver was restarted wouldn't that global variable be lost as well? Also, after restart if I were to directly go to user.php without visiting register.php the ROOT_PATH global would be undefined in the namespace, wouldn't it?

Comment: All the php variable / constants are lost when the PHP script ends. This is how PHP works.

Comment: Well then you need to include path.php.

Comment: @Trukken When I do include path.php I get this error message: Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\phpblogtut\app\controlers/app/database/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpblogtut\app\controlers\users.php on line 5

Comment: The slashes change and then I don't have another app folder after controlers and before data

Comment: Or now I don't get an error message on user, but I do get this one register: Warning: include(../../path.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpblogtut\app\controlers\users.php on line 4